Problems with a simple numerical integration in Python
I am trying to solve a simple integral in Python using different methods for numerical integration. However, when I try to calculate the integrals, I obtain wrong results for small values of my x coordinate. This is a messy because I am trying to solve some system of equations in which one of the variables I am evolving on time is the integral of some quantities. Of course, I don't have a functional form for the expression I want to integrate but instead I have an array of data (one f[i] for each x[i]). Do you know a way to obtain more accurate results of my integrals?
Here, I present a simple example of the problem I am having. Suppose I have some data that, for now, I will only consider a simple x^7 (in general I don't have a functional form for the functions I want to integrate, with this is just an example) and suppose I want to integrate such a function. The analytic solution of the integral is simple Int = x^8/8. Then, if I print or plot 8*Int/x^8 what I should have is that each entry of the output should be equal to one. Then, let me consider the following code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps 

x = np.linspace(0,10,101)
f = x**7
Int = np.array([simps(f[:i+1], x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))])
Div = 8*Int/(x**8)
Div[0] = 1 #To avoid division over zero
print(Div)

The output of this simple code is:
[1.           4.           1.375        1.2687090383 1.033203125
1.05997312   1.0069158665 1.0195120352 1.0022277832 1.0080582909
1.00092      1.0038955372 1.0004456376 1.0021034429 1.0002411835
 1.0012324471 1.0001416206 1.0007688345 1.0000885172 1.0005040075
 1.000058125  1.0003439529 1.0000397249 1.0002426572 1.0000280617
 1.0001760417 1.000020381  1.0001307892 1.000015157  1.0000991831
 1.0000115043 1.000076571  1.0000088885 1.0000600497 1.0000069756
 1.0000477527 1.0000055507 1.0000384478 1.0000044717 1.0000313025
 1.0000036426 1.0000257424 1.000002997  1.0000213637 1.0000024883
 1.0000178775 1.0000020831 1.0000150742 1.0000017571 1.0000127994
 1.0000014925 1.0000109379 1.0000012758 1.0000094029 1.0000010971
 1.0000081279 1.0000009486 1.0000070618 1.0000008244 1.000006165
 1.0000007199 1.000005406  1.0000006314 1.0000047604 1.0000005561
 1.0000042083 1.0000004917 1.000003734  1.0000004364 1.0000033246
 1.0000003886 1.0000029699 1.0000003472 1.0000026612 1.0000003112
 1.0000023916 1.0000002797 1.0000021553 1.0000002521 1.0000019475
 1.0000002278 1.0000017641 1.0000002064 1.0000016018 1.0000001874
 1.0000014577 1.0000001706 1.0000013295 1.0000001556 1.0000012151
 1.0000001422 1.0000011127 1.0000001303 1.0000010209 1.0000001195
 1.0000009384 1.0000001099 1.000000864  1.0000001012 1.0000007969
 1.0000000933]
 

As you can see, most of the results are very close to 1 (as expected) except for the points that are very close to the point x = 0. I need to have a good control of these integrals because I am using them for solving numerically a system of equations. The problem of having these bad results is that in my numerical scheme it ends giving me some gradients that ends destroying my numerical solutions. So, do you know a way to deal with this?
PS: If instead of using simps I use mpmath, I can obtain the correct result. However, mpmath works only for functions that we already know (as it is the case in this simple example of a x^7 function). However, as I previously mentioned, in reality I don't know a functional form of the expression I wan't to integrate and instead I only have an array of data.
PS2: I can also try to increase the size of my array x. But even if I do this, I always have errors in the first points closest to x = 0, and those errors end up ruining my numerical solutions.
Best regards, LP

I think it's not much about x=0, but it's about the fact that that Int contains integrations by only 1 point, then 2 points, then 3 points, etc. Of course it's coarse, so few data points. Try to set np.linspace(-10,10,101), you'll probably see the similar picture for first numbers

Given that for small x you are effectively doing "small"/"small" a better measure of error in this region would be the absolute error, Div = Int - (x**8)/8. This looks suitably small (at least near x=0).

As has been mentioned in the comments, you have two problems: first, x**8/8 for small x is tiny, and trying to calculate the relative error for tiny numbers is usually not very fruitful. 4e-8 and 1e-8 are pretty close together compared to f.max() =  10^7, despite the fact one is 400% of the other.
The second problem is Simpson's rule only has a few points to work with for those first couple of points. If you truly need good (relative) estimates even down to very small values of x, you need your f array to have more data (this is a common thing in many numerical integration methods, where the integration grid sometimes needs to be much finer than the evaluation grid). So you need to do something like this (where note np.linspace(0,10,1001)[::10] == np.linspace(0,10,101)):
x = np.linspace(0,10,1001)
f = x**7
Int = np.array([simps(f[:i+1], x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))])
Div = 8*Int[::10]/(x[::10]**8)
print(Div)

which prints
[       nan 1.00092    1.00005813 1.0000115  1.00000364 1.00000149
 1.00000072 1.00000039 1.00000023 1.00000014 1.00000009 1.00000006
 1.00000005 1.00000003 1.00000002 1.00000002 1.00000001 1.00000001
 1.00000001 1.00000001 1.00000001 1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
...


Having said this, knowing the restrictions of your particular case would probably be helpful in solving the problem, if this sort of decrease-grid-spacing method won't work for you.
